# Exporting data to excel

Tags: c#

the code works to a certain extent when I export the data to excel it works fine but if I go back into the application and add, delete or update any of the datagrid when I export the data again it doesn't export the changes. I have deleted the original csv file in case it was an overwriting problem but still get the same problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class FormAccounts : Form
    {
        String constring = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\kenny\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Cegees 181013\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Accounts.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
        //String cmdselect = @"select * Accounts";
        String cmdupdate = @"update Accounts set date = @date, moneyin = @moneyin, retailin = @retailin, rent = @rent, stock = @stock, transport = @transport, misc = @misc, bills = @bills, comments = @comments where ID = @id";
        String cmdinsert = @"insert into Accounts (date, moneyin, retailin, rent, stock, transport, misc, bills, comments) values (@date, @moneyin, @retailin, @rent, @stock, @transport, @misc, @bills, @comments )";
        String cmddelete = @"delete from Accounts where ID =@ID";

        public FormAccounts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormAccounts_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'accountsDataSet.Accounts' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.accountsTableAdapter.Fill(this.accountsDataSet.Accounts);

        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdinsert, con);

            try
            {

                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@date"].Value = dtpaccs.Value; 
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@moneyin", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@moneyin"].Value = textmoneyin.Text ;
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@retailin", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@retailin"].Value = textretailin.Text;
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@rent", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@rent"].Value = textrent.Text;
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@stock", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@stock"].Value = textstock.Text;
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@transport", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@transport"].Value = texttransport.Text;
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@misc", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@misc"].Value = textmisc.Text;
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@bills", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@bills"].Value = textbills.Text;
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@comments", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters["@comments"].Value = textcomments.Text;

                con.Open();
                da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
                con.Close();
                cleartexts();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {


            string date = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string id = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            lbldate.Text = date;
            lblID.Text = id;
            dtpaccs.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(date);            
            textmoneyin.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            textretailin.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textrent.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            textstock.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            texttransport.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            textmisc.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            textbills.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            textcomments.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Value.ToString();

        }

        private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdupdate, con);

            try
            {

                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lblID.Text;
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = lbldate.Text;
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@moneyin", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textmoneyin.Text;
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@retailin", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textretailin.Text;
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@rent", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textrent.Text;
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@stock", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textstock.Text;
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@transport", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = texttransport.Text;
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@misc", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textmisc.Text;
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@bills", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = textbills.Text;
                da.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@comments", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textcomments.Text;

                con.Open();
                da.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Accounts Updated");
                con.Close();
                cleartexts();


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

        }

        private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var rindex = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand(cmddelete, con);

            try
            {
                DialogResult dr;
                dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    da.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = accountsDataSet.Accounts[rindex].ID;
                    con.Open();
                    da.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
                    con.Close();
                    cleartexts();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Delete Cancelled");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

       public void cleartexts()
       {
            //Clears textboxes
                textmoneyin.Text = "";
                textretailin.Text ="";
                textrent.Text = "";
                textstock.Text = "";
                texttransport.Text = "";
                textmisc.Text = "";
                textbills.Text = "";
                textcomments.Text = "";
       }




        private void exportToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int cols;
                string directory = @"C:\Users\kenny\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Cegees 181013\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Excel Exports";
                string filename = string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yy}__{1}.csv", DateTime.Now, "Accounts");
                string path = Path.Combine(directory, filename);



                //open file

                using (StreamWriter wr = File.CreateText(path))
                {

                    //determine the number of cols and write to file
                    cols = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
                    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
                    {
                        wr.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name.ToString().ToUpper() + ",");
                    }
                    wr.WriteLine();

                    //write rows to excel
                    for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                        {
                            if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                            {
                                wr.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value + ",");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                wr.Write(",");
                            }
                        }
                        wr.WriteLine();
                    }
                    wr.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Operation Complete " +path);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you bind the DataGridView to your data source? I notice you export from the GridView but I don't see you updating the binding after your Insert/Update/Delete operations.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The application needs to be shut down and restarted for the new data to copy over. Is there a way to do that once the datagrid has been changed / updated?